Title of a Romantic War Movie
I saw this movie a while back on STARS or HBO - I barely remember. It's a war movie based on true story. New troops join the shooting camp in another country, but all are Americans. There are planes shooting in the air at opponents and over-taking them. One of crew members accidentally falls into a building or apartment, and girls in the building help him by giving him medicine he need to recover. Later he keeps on coming to visit that one girl who looked at him when he was in bad shape; she doesn't speak English, and they can barely communicate. In the end they never meet again , and it ends saying "he's still looking for her".

The movie you're talking about, this must be it, Flyboys

Can you please elaborate (and perhaps add a short synopsis)? Why do you think it fits the OP's description?
